# Running a command from a variable in make

Tags: windows, makefile

I'm running make for windows.   ( `choco install make` )

pretty much everything is working out fine until i'm trying to build a docker container, specifically to deploy on Amazon ECS....

Part of the ECS deploy process is you get a login from AWS
`aws ecr get-login`
this returns a string containing a command that looks like 
`docker login -u AWS -p AQEC...HGZSSUMX4ftIpo8gY2 -e none https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

if i was just running this from the shell i would copy the output and past it onto the commandline and run - but I'm trying to put this into my makefile so i have 
`@ECS_LOGIN =$(shell aws ecr get-login)`

and then I'm trying to execute it on the next line
`$(ECS_LOGIN)`

and thats where i get
`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ECS_LOGIN =docker login -u AWS -p AQEC...HGZSSUMX4ftIpo8gY2 -e none https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, ...) failed. 
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [docker-deploy] Error 2`

from researching other questions this seems like a pathing issue when running from windows 
[Makefile error make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33674973/13100)

but docker commands prior to my `aws ecr get-login` work just fine
ie
`docker build`
so it seems specific to running the command out of the variable

So how do i run this command from make and have the path resolve?

full recipe
`docker-deploy: docker-build
    @ECS_LOGIN =$(shell aws ecr get-login)
    $(ECS_LOGIN)
    docker tag mytag:latest 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
    docker push 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to decide which tool you want to use to run the "aws ecr get-login" command.  In your recipe, Make runs it (and you assign the result to a shell variable without quoting the multi-word value, but I guess the Windows shell is fine with it?).  In the next line you try to refer to the *shell* variable, but forget to dollar-quote the dollar sign, so make substitutes whatever the value of ECS_LOGIN is at the time of invoking the recipe (which is probably nothing).

Perhaps start by moving the first line (`ECS_LOGIN=$(shell aws ecr get-login)`) out of the shell recipe and see if that helps:

```
ECS_LOGIN =$(shell aws ecr get-login)
docker-deploy: docker-build
    @$(ECS_LOGIN)
    docker tag mytag:latest 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
    docker push 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
```

Comment: thanks - putting the variable  set outside the recipe seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile is confused about make variables vs. shell variables and how recipes are invoked; see Michael's answer.

If it were me I would just not bother to use a variable at all; is there a reason you want to do so?

You could use either:

```
docker-deploy: docker-build
        @$(shell aws ecr get-login)
        docker tag mytag:latest 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
        docker push 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
```

which will work but is a bit odd: running a `shell` function inside a recipe is confusing, because you're already in a shell, so an alternative is just to use the recipe shell completely and avoid make's `shell` function:

```
docker-deploy: docker-build
        @eval $$(aws ecr get-login)
        docker tag mytag:latest 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
        docker push 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mytag:latest
```