# Argon2 Makefile is throwing an error (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I am trying to use argon2 for C. I cloned the repo and tried to build it myself by typing `make` in the root directory of the repo. However, make threw this error:

```
Building without optimizations
cc -std=c89 -O3 -Wall -g -Iinclude -Isrc -pthread  src/argon2.c src/core.c 
src/blake2/blake2b.c src/thread.c src/encoding.c src/ref.c src/run.c -o argon2
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -std=c89 -O3 -Wall -g -Iinclude -Isrc - 
pthread src/argon2.c src/core.c src/blake2/blake2b.c src/thread.c 
src/encoding.c src/ref.c src/run.c -o argon2, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [argon2] Error 2
```

I referred to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) and I think I am getting this error because I do not have 'cc' installed. What is 'cc' and am I correct about 'cc' needing to be installed? I am on windows by the way. I know this is a super specific question but maybe someone can help me.

Comment: `cc` is the generic name for a C compiler. Based on the option flags, the Makefile is looking for `gcc`. Install `gcc` and make `cc` point to `gcc`.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 I have gcc installed already. should I find and replace all cc for gcc?

Comment: You _can_ do that, but there's probably a better way; makefiles typically define variables for that stuff. If you find a line like `CC := cc` in the makefile, you can just do `make CC=gcc` and it should work.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 that line already exists in the makefile

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 I fixed this thank you