# Windows 10 Makefile error make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, makefile

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- make 3.81
- docker CE 18.09.2
- docker compose 1.23.2
- git bash 2.22.0.windows.1

I've got a `docker-compose.yaml` file that looks like this:

```sh
version: '3.2'

services:
  terraform:
    image: hashicorp/terraform:0.11.14
    entrypoint: terraform
    working_dir: /var/tmp/code/
    volumes:
      - .:/var/tmp/code/:rw
```

And my `Makefile` looks like this

```sh
init:
    docker-compose run terraform init
```

When I run this from the GitBash command line:

```sh
make init
```

I get the following output

> docker-compose run terraform init
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, docker-compose run terraform init, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   make: *** [init] Error 2

I've seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) relating to this, and understand this to be a problem with the values on my `PATH` environment variable, however I'm not sure how to correct the problem.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information

---

**Update**

I have confirmed that:

- `docker-compose` is installed
- the `docker-compose.exe` exists on my PATH environment variable (see below)

My PATH environment variable:

[image]

---

**Update 2**

If I modify the makefile so it explicitly states the path to the `docker-compose.exe` file, it works:

```sh
init:
    "/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose.exe" run terraform init
```

---

**Update 3 - Solution**

So my full `Makefile` actually looked like this:

```sh
#!make
include .env
export

.env:
    @[ -f ./.env-aws ] && source ./.env-aws; env | grep AWS | sed 's/export //g; s/"//g' > .env

init-test:
    docker-compose run terraform init
```

Running `make .env` creates a `.env file`, which included a PATH env var

```sh
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=...
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
PATH=...
```

Deleting the `PATH` line from this file solve it for me :)

Comment: Your screen shot seems to imply that it's installed at `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin\docker-compose.exe` - can you confirm that this is indeed the case? (Really `ProgramData` not `Program Files`?) What happens if you use the full path in the `Makefile`? (Your `Makefile` would not happen to override `PATH` in a part you are not showing?)

Comment: And as always, have you explored getting rid of Windows?

Comment: @tripleee, Windows === corporate policy!

Comment: @tripleee, yes, if i explicitly state the path to `docker-compose.exe` (which is in the location stated in the screenshot), it works.  Will update the question

Comment: So does your `Makefile` muck with `PATH`? Or does it get lost somehow (what happens if you add `echo "$$PATH"` on a separate tab-indented line after `init:`)?

Comment: You were spot on!  There is a another command in the `Makefile` that creates' a `.env` file.  That had created it's own PATH variable which was overriding the system PATH.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to post a solution and I'll mark it as an answer so you get the rep ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Makefile` somehow manipulates the `PATH` variable so that the directory where `docker-compose` is installed is no longer on it, that would cause this kind of symptom.

For troubleshooting, try to add

```
echo "$$PATH"
```

(indented by a tab, of course) just before the failing command, and examine whether the result confirms your expectations.

(The dollar sign needs to be doubled in this context to pass a literal dollar sign from `make` to the underlying shell.)

Answer (score 0):

This means `docker-compose` not found when execute `docker-compose run terraform init` in Makefile.

If you not execute `make`, just `docker-compose`, you also cannot find `docker-compose`.

a) If you haven't installed `docker-compose`, download it from [official release site](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) to install it, a direct download link for your reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0-rc1/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe

b) If you have installed `docker-compose`, you need to know where you install it. For my site, I installed it in: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin`, so before execute `make init`, I add this to PATH:

```
C:\abc\try>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;%PATH%
C:\abc\try>make init
```

Also, if you want to permanently add the `docker-compose` path to env, you can reference [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @atline, but I have `docker-compose` installed and the `docker-compose.exe` exists on my PATH env var - I'll update the question with that info