# Windows 10 Makefile source The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: makefile, git-bash

I have a very simple makefile that I'm trying to execute in git-bash on a Windows 10 machine.

The contents of the makefile are:

```
start:
    source env.sh
```

Where `env.sh` is a local file that exists.

If I execute the command `make start` I receive the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, source env.sh, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:2: start] Error 2
```

However, if I execute `source env.sh` at the command prompt all is well and I receive no error at all.

I've seen other posts like this [Windows 10 Makefile error make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692104/windows-10-makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) which report a similar error, but the linked question is to do with docker being on the path which I don't think applies here.

Is there any reason why the makefile errors but typing the command does not?

Comment: Is that really the complete recipe?  Just `source env.sh` and nothing else?  Because that won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows by default, GNU make always runs the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.  The recipe that you're running here is a `bash` command.

You say it works *at the command prompt* but that's because the command prompt you're using is from Git bash; if you opened a Windows terminal and typed that command it wouldn't work.

If you want to use a different shell than the default you need to set the `SHELL` make variable in your makefile:

```
SHELL := <path to git bash>
```

Comment: Using `echo $(SHELL)` in my makefile outputs `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe`, so I don't think cmd is being used here.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you, but that error message is what you get when make thinks it's running `cmd.exe`, where `source` is not a shell built-in.  I recommend you explicitly set SHELL as I mentioned above and see if it works.  Or, if you have that `bin` directory in your `PATH` you could just use `SHELL := sh.exe` and see if that works.

Comment: I've done that, still get the same error as in the original question

Comment: OK, try this: change your `source env.sh` to `. env.sh` which is the POSIX compliant way to write this (`source` is a bash extension to the POSIX standard).  Do you have a `bash.exe` in your Git bin directory?  If you set `SHELL` to the `bash.exe` does that failure go away when you use `source env.sh`?