# Why is my "clean" rule in makefile not working?

Tags: powershell, makefile

I am new to make, and was playing around makefile. I did grasp an introductory knowledge about how the make and makefile works and how to write very basic rules. In various articles over the internet, there are examples of using a clean rule to delete object or executable files. It's pretty straight forward,

```
clean :
    rm -f filename
```

I found out that, `rm -f filename`, does not work in powershell (atleast for me), so was using `rm filename` which works in powershell.

My makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

%: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
    ./$@

%.c:
    subl $@

clean:
    rm hello.exe
```

I have couple of file in the working directory, and I want my clean rule to remove the 'hello.exe' file. Previous rules do work but, `mingw32-make` gives an error. I don't know why, after running the same command (recipe) explicitly in powershell, it works. Also there is isn't any file named clean to create conflicts. All I know is that the rule is getting called but, `rm hello.exe` is not working when called from makefile.

[image: Powershell]

From powershell, (incase the image doesn't load properly)

```
PS F:\home\learnC> ls


    Directory: F:\home\learnC


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        04-09-2021     21:31                articles
d-----        31-07-2021     10:06                books
-a----        02-08-2021     21:45           1872 .hello.c.un~
-a----        12-08-2021     12:23          40766 a.exe
-a----        04-09-2021     21:58            410 format.c
-a----        04-09-2021     21:58          42446 format.exe
-a----        04-09-2021     21:10            211 hello.c
-a----        05-09-2021     13:04          41934 hello.exe
-a----        05-09-2021     12:57            110 makefile


PS F:\home\learnC> rm -f hello.exe
Remove-Item : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-Filter -Force.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -f hello.exe
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS F:\home\learnC> mingw32-make clean
rm hello.exe
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm hello.exe, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:12: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make: *** [clean] Error 2
PS F:\home\learnC> rm hello.exe
PS F:\home\learnC> ls


    Directory: F:\home\learnC


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        04-09-2021     21:31                articles
d-----        31-07-2021     10:06                books
-a----        02-08-2021     21:45           1872 .hello.c.un~
-a----        12-08-2021     12:23          40766 a.exe
-a----        04-09-2021     21:58            410 format.c
-a----        04-09-2021     21:58          42446 format.exe
-a----        04-09-2021     21:10            211 hello.c
-a----        05-09-2021     12:57            110 makefile


PS F:\home\learnC>
```

I also tried using a verbose command for rm as suggested from comment section, but it still gives an error.

```
PS F:\home\learnC> mingw32-make clean
Remove-Item -Force hello.exe
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, Remove-Item -Force hello.exe, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:12: recipe for target 'clean' failed
mingw32-make: *** [clean] Error 2
PS F:\home\learnC>
```

How do I fix this error? Also is there any way to use `make` instead of `mingw32-make`?

`C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe` the one I use.

`C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe` curious what this is?

Comment: Please do not post text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Using `make` with Powershell is unusual. Most Makefiles you will find are written for a Unix shell like Bash (or, well, actually, `sh`, but Bash is probably easier to find and install for Windows). The error message looks vaguely like `make` tries to run a command named `rm hello.exe` rather than `rm` with `hello.exe` as its argument, but perhaps this is normal for Windows (I guess CreateProcess should normally be able to figure out how to split the command line?)

Comment: kaylum, sorry I know that, but text was not getting highlighted and it looked all monotonous.

Comment: triplee, I did used debian earlier on my old system, but this system is new and windows was preinstalled, so I am a little nervous to go dual boot on this one, last time I accidently erased windows :| Anyways, I'll do it soon.

Comment: As an aside, an interactive command like `subl` is not really suitable for a `Makefile`; you want to automate the things which can be automated but creating new files in a manual process anyway. (Assuming this is running Sublime Text, a text editor.)

Comment: Olaf, thanks for telling that, I'll update my question.

Comment: I'm not saying get rid of Windows (though that is probably the best possible advice in many situations), I'm just trying to explain how this is unusual and thus perhaps hard to guess what your expectations are exactly. I'm sort of assuming you hoped it would be a common thing to do and straightforward to understand.

Comment: triplee, that rule works fine, I was just playing around makefile. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Olaf, I did see your comment, I think -f is for force delete, so have updated the command in my makefile. The problem still persists, working in powershell but not from makefile.

Comment: This is confusing. The error for the first command you tried was an issue with the syntax, as it mentions. Powershell tries to auto resolve parameters for you and when specifying just `-f`, it doesn't know if it's `-Force`, or `-Filter`. You need to use at least another letter to distinguish what you mean (*when not using the full parameter name*): `-Fo` for force. Regarding your .exe call, it says it can't find the file.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that it doesn't matter what shell you are using before you invoke `make`.  That would be absolutely disastrous for portability.  `make` always uses the same shell, unless the makefile specifically changes the shell.  On a POSIX system it always uses `/bin/sh` (the default shell).  On a Windows system it depends on exactly how the binary was created, but generally for MinGW (as I understand it), the default shell is `cmd.exe`.  The command you're trying to run `rm -f` is a POSIX command.  It won't work on Windows, unless you have a POSIX environment installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use GNU Makefiles with powershell core commands regularly. I use this snippet at the top of my makefiles to change to pwsh:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    SHELL := pwsh.exe
else
   SHELL := pwsh
endif
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command
```

I just did a quick test and I get the same error as you without this snippet. And when I add it to my makefile the `rm hello.exe` command works as expected.

I don't know the differences between mingw32 and gnu make. [GNU make](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/make) has been solid for me, and using pwsh core helps make my makefiles cross platform, more explicit, and imo easier to develop because I can use a scripting language that me/my team are comfortable with.

Comment: I had same problem, but I don't have the pwsh on my win11, so SHELL=powershell was used. What solved it for me was the SHELLFLAGS. Thanks for the hint.