# powershell makefile not recognizing get-childitem command

Tags: powershell, makefile

I'm trying to use the powershell version of `make` in order to streamline some commands that I need to run multiple times. One of these such commands goes like this:

`get-childitem -file | where {($_.extension -ne ".tex") -and ($_.extension -ne ".pdf") -and ($_.name -ne "Makefile")} | remove-item`

I therefore set it up in the makefile as follows:

```
clean:
        get-childitem -file | where {($_.extension -ne ".tex") -and ($_.extension -ne ".pdf") -and ($_.name -ne "Makefile")} | remove-item
```

When I run `make clean` however I get an error:

```
get-childitem -file | where {(.extension -ne ".tex") -and (.extension -ne ".pdf") -and (.name -ne "Makefile")} | remove-item
'get-childitem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:5: clean] Error 255
```

Why do I get this error and am I allowed to use powershell commands within the Makefile as shown above?

Comment: As an aside: You can streamline your command to: `get-childitem -file * -Exclude *.tex, *.pdf, Makefile | remove-item -WhatIf` (`-WhatIf` previews what would be removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, **[`make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) uses `cmd.exe` as its default shell**, not PowerShell.

You can **instruct [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to use PowerShell** by placing the following at the top of your `Makefile`s; adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69064732/45375):

Windows-only, using *Windows PowerShell*:

```sh
SHELL := powershell.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 

# Sample target that echoes information about the PowerShell edition and version.
# Note:
#  * '@' preceding a command prevents the command itself from getting echoed.
#  * '$' has special meaning to `make` itself, so to pass a verbatim '$'
#    through to PowerShell, it must be escaped as '$$' 
.PHONY: demo
demo:
    @$$PSVersionTable
```

Windows-only, using *PowerShell (Core) 7+*:

```sh
SHELL := pwsh.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 

.PHONY: demo
demo:
    @$$PSVersionTable
```

Cross-platform, using Windows PowerShell on *Windows* (and, of necessity, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* on *Unix*-like platforms):

```sh
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    SHELL := powershell.exe
else
    SHELL := pwsh
endif
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 

.PHONY: demo
demo:
    @$$PSVersionTable
```

Cross-platform, using PowerShell (Core) 7+ on all platforms:

```sh
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    # Note: .exe is *required* on Windows; otherwise, 
    #       make.exe quietly falls back to cmd.exe
    SHELL := pwsh.exe
else
    SHELL := pwsh
endif
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 

.PHONY: demo
demo:
    @$$PSVersionTable
```

Note:

- The assumption is that `pwsh` / `pwsh.exe`, *PowerShell (Core)*'s [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), can be located via `$env:PATH`, which the official installers ensure, but you can use a full path if needed.

  - Note: As noted, on Windows you *must* include `.exe` in the file name / path. If `make` cannot find the executable, it quietly falls back to the default shell (`cmd.exe` on Windows, `/bin/sh` on Unix-like platforms).
- The built-in *Windows PowerShell* CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), is in `$env:PATH` by default.