# Stop make shell interpreting arrow up

Tags: bash, powershell, gnu-make, typeahead, ansi-escape

I will describe first environment:

Windows pc, running `make` in powershell. Make is using bash as its shell. I also use Windows terminal. So powershell is running in Windows terminal, calling of make target.

Problem:

When I run any target (that has at least some shell call) and press eg. arrow up, at the end of make call, I get `[A` printed in powershell.

My goal is to get arrow up action in powershell to load previous command. This way, I can quickly just type `make clean` followed by arrow up to get history command from powershell `make build`. This used to work previously, but I have no idea what exactly changed. It seems that make calls bash and bash is interpreting my arrow up as escape sequence that gets sent to powershell without `esc` seqeunce.

I tried to insert into my `.bashrc` `set keyseq-timeout` either to `0`, or some big value, nothing helped.

Also, this happens in powershell standalone, or even in cmd.

How to get it working as previously?

Comment: Ctrl+D should quit bash and return to PowerShell prompt

Comment: I dont want to quit make call. During make call, I want to pre enter arrow up for powershell. I know it worked previously. Not sure though, if make wasn't configured to not use bash shell, instead windows equivalent (maybe cmd calls for echo, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

- It works when you're calling *from a Bash environment*, such as WSL or Git Bash.

  - From WSL, `^[[A`<sup>[1]</sup> is getting printed if you press the up-arrow while a command is still running, but the buffered keystroke *does* take effect after the command terminates; the behavior is the same in Git Bash, except that `^[[A` does *not* print.
- When calling *from a native Windows shell*, such as `cmd.exe` or PowerShell,   that shell does *not* receive the buffered keystroke; instead, it is *handled by the terminal (console)* itself.

  - This is in effect a *no-op*: the cursor moves up one line in the terminal, but then the Windows-native shell regains control and prints its prompt string on the original line, followed by placing the cursor at the end.
  - I'm unclear on the exact reason, but I suspect it is related to the fact that *two* shells are involved, and that the buffered keystroke, due to the Bash shell having exited along with the command, isn't handled by Bash and also isn't passed to the outer, Windows-native shell, causing the terminal emulator to interpret it.

    - Frankly, I'd be surprised if this behaved differently in the past, i.e. if this ever worked - but if you can pinpoint a specific scenario in which it did, do tell us.
- If you want to stick with using Bash as the shell in your Makefiles, the next section provides - imperfect - *workarounds*.

  - In order to make typeahead work they way you expect, you'll need to modify your Makefiles to use either `cmd.exe` or PowerShell for shell commands, which involves both placing a `SHELL` statement at the top - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69237589/45375) - and changing the actual shell commands to PowerShell commands.

---

**Workarounds with Bash as the Makefile shell**:

If the aim is to simply recall the previous command *and execute it right away*, you can use PowerShell's [`Invoke-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-history) cmdlet, whose built-in alias is `r` (presumably short for *r*ecall):

```bash
# Execute `make clean`, then recall and execute the previous command.
make clean; r
```

Note: If you want to make the re-execution contingent on `make clean` signaling *success*, use
`make clean && r` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and
`make clean; if (0 -eq $LASTEXITCODE) { r }` in *Windows PowerShell*. The same applies analogously to the other commands below.

Of course, if you know ahead of time that `make build` is the next command you want to execute, simply make it part of the same command line; e.g.:

```bash
# PS 7+ syntax - only executes `make build` if `make clean` succeeded.
make clean && make build
```

If you fully want to emulate the up-arrow behavior, i.e. if you want to recall the previous command *without instantly executing it*, i.e. if you only want to place it in the command-line edit buffer:

- First, define a helper function that simulates pressing the up-arrow key (twice, because at the time it executes the previous command is the *penultimate* one, because the current one has already been recorded):

  ```bash
  # Helper function
  function u {
    (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('{UP 2}')
  }
  ```
- Then call `u` in lieu of `r`:

  ```bash
  make clean; u
  ```

---

<sup>[1] `^[` represents the ESC character, and the whole sequence - `ESC [ A` - is presumably what [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm)-compatible terminal emulators emit when the up-arrow key is pressed. Many shells intercept this keystroke and interpret it to mean: recall the most recently submitted command and place it in the command-line edit buffer. In the absence of a shell, the cursor moves one line up from the current line.</sup>

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answer. 
First, I dont know always what is the previous command, scenarios can be different. Also I do not like passing second command. 
To understand me, this is preference, and habbit, that when I run make, ussually i want to clean and build. For our specific case, I quickly type "make clean" follow by arrow up press, and enter. This used to ensure I would clean and build if previous command was to build. But as I said, not always build was previous command so lets assume previous command is unknown.

Comment: Regarding this working. I know for sure, in my previous job, we run make in powerhell, and I could do this. But Im not sure if make was configured to use bash as shell, or not.

Comment: Just some other observations I didn't mention. This doesn't only happen when using arrow up. Sometime I know second command I want to type out. So I type it out, and it does appear on the powershell, but sometime "[m" or just additional "m" appears. I think it is again bash interpreting some keystroke as escape sequence. And again, I know for sure, this didn't use to happen. So you are right that native shell gets control back, prints prompt, but also prints keys I pressed during execution of first make... But sometime, it inserts these "[m" "m" characters...

Comment: @JanBenedek, yes, the likeliest explanation is that you used a version of make that didn't use Bash. While it does involve a second command, `make clean; r` _does_ recall _whatever the previous command was_. Given the circumstances, I suspect this is the best solution available to you. How did you install `make`? Is it an `*.exe`? How does it invoke Bash, and what Bash implementation is it?

Comment: @JanBenedek, to make type-ahead work you could switch to using PowerShell as the shell used by your Makefiles, but that obviously requires modifying them.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. We seem to have special version of cygwin (maybe it is not special, just not latest version). When I switched to that, now I can press any key and it is interpreted correctly by powershell and no interference from bash happens.

Comment: @JanBenedek, glad to hear it; I'd be happy to add the information to the answer, but I'm unclear on what you did: Are you calling a `make` version that came with Cygwin from PowerShell? Other than possibly not being the latest version, what makes it special, and how was it created?