# Why does make not find the file specified?

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing a makefile in which everything works if I type it into git bash, but when trying to use the command through make, it wont work.

Makefile

```
CC ?= gcc
CFLAGS ?= -Wall
INCLUDE_DIR ?= src/headers

TARGET_EXEC ?= o.exe
SRC_DIR ?= src
BIN_DIR ?= bin
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS := $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC)

$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Console output

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -Wall -c src/main.c -o bin/main.o -Isrc/headers, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:17: recipe for target 'bin/main.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [bin/main.o] Error 2
```

I have already tried reinstalling git, vscode, mingw. I have also tried removing
enviroment variables.

I also stumbled onto this answer: [Makefile error make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)
Which also did not work for me.

I have also checked which shell is being used by typing `echo $(SHELL)`, which outputs sh.exe

Comment: If you just type `cc` into a Command Prompt window, does it work?

Comment: The file that cannot be found is `cc`, check that cc as a command works and at least one of the directories in `$(PATH)` points to your mingw install directory.

Comment: @teapot418 CC does not work, but my path already points to my mingw directory because the gcc command works.

Comment: Why is it trying to launch cc anyway? `CC ?= gcc` If you wanted to run gcc, you might want to make this unconditional or clear your CC environment variable. (`?=` is assign only if not already assigned, did you mean `=` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar and @teapos418, I found the answer.
The file not found was indeed CC, because the variable $(CC) was declared by using `CC ?= gcc`, wich is not the right use case. Changing it to `CC = gcc` fixed the problem.

makefile manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html