# process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, true, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, mingw

I am using mingw64 (on windows 11) to run a makefile but get the following error:

```
cc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-unknown-warning-option    -O3 prog.c -o prog
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, true, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:431: all] Error 2
```

A similar questions was asked here: [Makefile error make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

I have cleaned up my path as suggested (and windows restart), however to no avail.

I'm stuck.

Comment: `true` is a POSIX command.  It doesn't exist on Windows.  This makefile you're trying to use was written for a POSIX system like Linux or MacOS, and can't be run on Windows unless you go change it to work on Windows.

Comment: well, `true` probably does exist in mingw.

Answer (score 2):

This answer on the linked question worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816749/121921

If you have `git` installed then you likely have a `<git>\usr\bin` folder which contains a full set of utilities you are likely to need and which can be invoked from CMD, PowerShell or `sh` (which make is most likely using).
`mingw64` will have its own `\usr\bin` directory I expect.