# Makefile error for fastText on windows - make (e=2)

Tags: makefile, build, fasttext

I'm trying to use [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/support.html) on my windows computer and I when I try to build the project using make command (I installed Make v3.81), I have this error :

```
c++ -pthread -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -c src/args.cc
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, c++ -pthread -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -c src/args.cc, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [args.o] Error 2
```

I'm totally new to using make and makefile, here is what the beginning of the makefile looks like :

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2016-present, Facebook, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
#

CXX = c++
CXXFLAGS = -pthread -std=c++11 -march=native
OBJS = args.o autotune.o matrix.o dictionary.o loss.o productquantizer.o densematrix.o quantmatrix.o vector.o model.o utils.o meter.o fasttext.o
INCLUDES = -I.

opt: CXXFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG
opt: fasttext

coverage: CXXFLAGS += -O0 -fno-inline -fprofile-arcs --coverage
coverage: fasttext

debug: CXXFLAGS += -g -O0 -fno-inline
debug: fasttext

wasm: webassembly/fasttext_wasm.js

wasmdebug: export EMCC_DEBUG=1
wasmdebug: webassembly/fasttext_wasm.js
```

I have checked [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) on a similar error, but they were some specifics differences with their errors which doesn't seem to apply to my error.

**Update (11/01/2023) :**

As per suggested by MadScientist in bellow comments, I used WSL to run the program on ubuntu. I'm using Python 3.10.12 and g++ 11.4.0. I also installed numpy and scipy as required to build fastText.

Here is the new error I have when running make on the fastText directory under Ubuntu :

The beginning of the error :

```
c++ -pthread -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG args.o autotune.o matrix.o dictionary.o loss.o productquantizer.o densematrix.o quantmatrix.o vector.o model.o utils.o meter.o fasttext.o src/main.cc -o fasttext
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `args.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.text.unlikely+0x36): undefined reference to `__ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_createERjj'
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.text.unlikely+0x7f): undefined reference to `__ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc'
/usr/bin/ld: autotune.o: in function `fasttext::Autotune::printArgs(fasttext::Args const&, fasttext::Args const&)':
autotune.cc:(.text+0x123b): undefined reference to `fasttext::Args::lossToString[abi:cxx11](fasttext::loss_name) const'
/usr/bin/ld: autotune.o: in function `fasttext::Autotune::quantize(fasttext::Args&, fasttext::Args const&)':
autotune.cc:(.text+0x1c8d): undefined reference to `fasttext::Args::getAutotuneModelSize() const'
/usr/bin/ld: autotune.cc:(.text+0x1d6b): undefined reference to `fasttext::Args::getAutotuneModelSize() const'
/usr/bin/ld: autotune.o: in function `fasttext::AutotuneStrategy::AutotuneStrategy(fasttext::Args const&, unsigned long)':
autotune.cc:(.text+0x2196): undefined reference to `fasttext::Args::Args()'
/usr/bin/ld: autotune.o: in function `fasttext::AutotuneStrategy::ask(double)':
```

The end of the error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_RKS8_+0x13): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZNKSt10_HashtableINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_SaIS5_ENSt8__detail9_IdentityESt8equal_toIS5_ESt4hashIS5_ENS7_18_Mod_range_hashingENS7_20_Default_ranged_hashENS7_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS7_17_Hashtable_traitsILb1ELb1ELb1EEEE5countERKS5_+0x13): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt10_HashtableIcSt4pairIKciESaIS2_ENSt8__detail10_Select1stESt8equal_toIcESt4hashIcENS4_18_Mod_range_hashingENS4_20_Default_ranged_hashENS4_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS4_17_Hashtable_traitsILb0ELb0ELb1EEEE9_M_rehashEjRKj+0x13): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt10_HashtableIcSt4pairIKciESaIS2_ENSt8__detail10_Select1stESt8equal_toIcESt4hashIcENS4_18_Mod_range_hashingENS4_20_Default_ranged_hashENS4_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS4_17_Hashtable_traitsILb0ELb0ELb1EEEE21_M_insert_unique_nodeEjjPNS4_10_Hash_nodeIS2_Lb0EEE+0x13): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/bin/ld: args.o:args.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt10_HashtableINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_SaIS5_ENSt8__detail9_IdentityESt8equal_toIS5_ESt4hashIS5_ENS7_18_Mod_range_hashingENS7_20_Default_ranged_hashENS7_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS7_17_Hashtable_traitsILb1ELb1ELb1EEEE9_M_rehashEjRKj+0x13): more undefined references to `___gxx_personality_v0' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error is much longer than that with a bunch of "undefined references" in between.

Comment: Note that per the page you've linked, "fastText builds on modern Mac OS and Linux distributions" – & while I've seen reports of people eventually figuring out what's needed to successfully build on Windows, I've never seen a claim of support for Windows builds from the Facebook project team. So, unless you find a step-by-step Windows-focused guide to building that particulr codebase, it may be a tricky & error-prone process for someone "new to using make and makefile".

Comment: The immediate problem is probably that `make` tries to run `c++` but you don't have a program with this name in your `PATH`, or probably installed on your computer at all. If you have a C++ compiler with a different name, try `make CXX=mickey-mouse++` or whatever your compiler is called.

Comment: ... Having said that, if the code isn't specifically written to be portable to Windows, this was by far your smallest hurdle. Getting rid of Windows may easily be the simplest solution if you are not specifically seeking to learn how to port C++ code from Unix-like platforms to Windows.

Comment: In support of @tripleee's excellent advice, I recommend using WSL.  I've played with it a bit and it seems quite usable and far simpler than dual-booting or installing a virtual machine like VMPlayer or VirtualBox.

Comment: Secondly just to note, GNU Make 3.81 is over 17 years out of date now (released in 2006).  You should get a newer version, if you're going to be asking for help using it since replies may refer to features added since then.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I installed WSL, I have a different error, my post have been updated.