# make Error 2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: makefile, path

I want to start a [make tutorial](https://makefiletutorial.com/#getting-started), but i run into the problem of the following error...

```
PS C:\localfiles\02_Programming\make> make
sh.exe
cc blah.c -o blahf 
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc blah.c -o blahf, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:4: blah] Error 2
```

My setup looks like this.

- Makefile:

```
$(info $(SHELL))

blah: blah.c
    cc blah.c -o blahf
```

- blah.c

```
// blah.c
int main() { return 0; }
```

My make version is:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I already tried to mess around with my path variables, like suggested in the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674973/makefile-error-make-e-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

I quiet don´t fully understand the problem though what it has to do with my git path...

Any suggestions what can i try next?

Comment: `make` is trying to run a C compiler named `cc`, exactly as your makefile directs it to do. It does not find such a program in its execution environment.  This could be an issue with the executable search path, but it also could easily be that you don't have a program by that name.  Either way, there is no indication that `make` is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: Ah....

ok... now i get it... thanks!
i don´t have cc installed... it works now when i use gcc instead...!!!